# ClassCastException:String to ArrayList cast throws exception

Tags: android, classcastexception

I have the following function in MainActivity:

```
private void exportToMail(String[] tos)
{
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, tos);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "gradius data ver: " + getAppVersion());
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getFormattedData());

    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File fileIn : new File(getExportFolder(this)).listFiles())
    {
        uris.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.file_provider_authority),fileIn));
    }

    if(!uris.isEmpty())
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

    //This is where the error occurs according to the Logcat.
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Pick an Email provider")); 
}
```

When I try to run this code I have the attached message in the Logcat.

```
2019-04-02 14:05:58.566 10783-10783/com.crowdx.gradius.testapp W/Bundle: Key android.intent.extra.TEXT expected ArrayList<CharSequence> but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
2019-04-02 14:05:58.567 10783-10783/com.crowdx.gradius.testapp W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getCharSequenceArrayList(BaseBundle.java:1302)
        at android.os.Bundle.getCharSequenceArrayList(Bundle.java:1076)
        at android.content.Intent.getCharSequenceArrayListExtra(Intent.java:8227)
        at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:11093)
        at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:11056)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1666)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4688)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4646)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5007)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4975)
        at com.crowdx.gradius_sdk.testApp.ui.activities.MainActivity.exportToMail(MainActivity.java:523)
        at com.crowdx.gradius_sdk.testApp.ui.activities.MainActivity.selectedStrings(MainActivity.java:485)
        at com.crowdx.gradius_sdk.testApp.ui.components.MultiSelectionSpinner$1.onClick(MultiSelectionSpinner.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:184)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

I don't understand what is wrong with this code, because `putExtra()` can have String array as a parameter, so what's wrong here?

**EDIT:**

//This is where the error occurs according to the Logcat.

```
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Pick an Email provider"));
```

Comment: Can you mention which line of the method is throwing this? It seems like the `EXTRA_TEXT` one, in which case please add the code for the `getFormattedData` method.

Comment: Yes, I actually put a comment above it, in the code snippet, but I will edit my question so it would much clearer

Comment: Ah, I missed that comment. My bad

Comment: @Keselme i got the same error few days back... have you tried my answer.. ?

Comment: well, I bet that `uris.isEmpty()` is true ... so you do not provide `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM` then with `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` is expected to be an `ArrayList<CharSequence>` ... **but it is blind guess** .... also this is what error says

Comment: after debugging I see that uris has some values in it, so it's not empty, still I get this error.

Comment: I have the same issue any solution?

Comment: I have the same issue. It is definitely complaining about the EXTRA_TEXT parameter not being 'ArrayList<CharSequence>'. I pass as String and it works fine, but generates this error. If instead I pass an ArrayList<CharSequence> to EXTRA_TEXT, no text shows up. I guess we just live with the error.

Answer (score 0):

If it not important to send your text and data together and if you want the put somthing in the attachment you can delete to this line:emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getFormattedData());
I didnt find a method where to different types of the data, text.
This is an old question but maybe it helps someone

it's worked for me